# Assign a key name in pre put hook: inheritance from a general ndb model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have this (working) model:

```
class WorkingModel(ndb.Model):
    # ...some properties...
    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        self.key = ndb.Key(WorkingModel, slugify(self.name))
```

What if I want to generalize the solution via inheritance? i.e.:

```
class slugModel(ndb.Model):
    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        self.key = ndb.Key(???, slugify(self.name))

class WorkingModel(slugModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.__class__` as argument.